# Isolated process not allowed to call startService

Tags: android, android-service

I am runnng Android Isolation service using the below manifest properties :

```
 <service
        android:name=".IsolationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:label="Isolation Service 2.0"
        android:process=":remote"
        android:permission="com.test.ISOLATION_PERMISSION"/>
```

when i try to call another service or content provider i got the blow message :
Isolated process not allowed to call startService, is there a way to solve this issue while i need to run service as an isolated process

Comment: What are the "android:process" values for the other service and the content provider?

Comment: What do you mean about "android:process" values for the other servic? What i am looking for is to run another service from isolated service and call custom content provider to do  CURD operations

Comment: As per the error message, this is not allowed. Sounds like an isolated process is not the right tool for your use case.